# I am getting Error in KeyedSubtree In Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-material, flutter-update

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HJzV.png)

it was working till noon but now its not working

it should work properly.
The class 'KeyedSubtree' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.
Try using one of the named constructors defined in 'KeyedSubtree'.dartnew_with_undefined_constructor_default
Type: KeyedSubtree
this error i am getting now .

Comment: That's strange. What Flutter version are you on? Did you (maybe accidentally) edit Flutter files (precisely `flutter/lib/src/widgets/basic.dart`, around line 7538)?

Comment: I am on latest version of flutter.

Comment: What about the second question?